# How to open files without using default App in Electron?

Tags: windows, electron

I know Electron's API [openPath](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellopenpathpath) to open file by default app. For example, png file will be opened by `Photos` application if I set Photos as my default app to open png file in Windows.

But my goal is to let user chooses different apps to open file instead of default app every time.

This function is similar to `open with` when you right click the file and then choose another app to open it in Windows.

["open with" screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFFIs.png)

So, is there any way to achieve my goal by using Electron'S API or any workaround?

Comment: related [question](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26598)

Comment: @pushkin Thanks for your reply. It seems shell.openExternal uses the verb `open` to execute file. It still can't show the  native "Open with" context menu.
I found a workaround to achieve my goal by calling `C:\Windows\System32\openwith.exe` to show the native dialog.